# VSCode C++ - #include <thread>

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code with C++ extension and g++ as my compiler. I'm trying to get my environment configured for threading but not having much luck. I tried installing POSIX threading via MinGW Installer but I'm not really sure how to include it properly in my project or include paths.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void task1(string msg){
    cout << "task1 says: " << msg;
}

int main(){
    std::thread t1(task1, "Hello");
    t1.join();
}
```

In this case #include  does not an error but std::thread is undefined.

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "name": "Win32",
    "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
    "includePath": [
        "${workspaceRoot}",
        "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++",
        "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/mingw32",
        "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/backward",
        "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include",
        "C:/MinGW/include",
        "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed"
    ],
    "defines": [
        "_DEBUG",
        "UNICODE",
        "__GNUC__=6",
        "__cdecl=__attribute__((__cdecl__))",
        "__SIZE_TYPE__=long long unsigned int"
    ],
    "browse": {
        "path": [
            "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include",
            "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed",
            "C:/MinGW/include/*"
        ],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
        "databaseFilename": ""
    },
    "cStandard": "c11",
    "cppStandard": "c++17"
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve], compiler version and compilation switches. Specifically are you compiling in C++11 mode with `-std=c++11` or above?

Comment: Which version of `gcc` are you using? Ancient versions still use C++03 as the default.

Comment: I'm using gcc 6.3.0 and not specifying any compilation switches. Post edited with more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out thread isn't really supported...

```
#include <thread>
```

But POSIX threads are so I ended up using them instead:

```
#include <pthread.h>
```